# Round a float in a function

Tags: python, format

Following function is not working:

```
def myround(sfloat, dec):
    print("{0:."+str(dec)+"f}")    # only to show the string formed.
    return ("{0:."+str(dec)+"f}".format(sfloat))

myround(2.35698, 2)
```

The error is:

```
{:.2f}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mytest.py", line 8, in <module>
    myround(2.35698, 2)
  File "mytest.py", line 6, in myround
    return ("{0:."+str(dec)+"f}".format(sfloat))
ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string
```

The first print function shows proper string: `{:.2f}`. I tried `{0:.2f}` but that also does not work. `\{` and `\}` also do not work.

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` has precedence over `+`. Try this: `("{0:."+str(dec)+"f}").format(sfloat)`

Comment: It was so simple. Thanks.